# Insert embedded documents Mongo DB from express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I have a mongo db schema like so

```
users:
{username:"",
 age: "",
 data: [ 
      {field1:"", field2:""},
      {field1:"", field2:""}
]

}
```

My problem is how do send over my user object to my express route to post data to the db.

Typically i create my user object like so:

```
var user= {username:"test" age: 20};
```

and send this user object with my ajax call to my adduser route.

Ho do i structure my above assignment to include my embedded documents.

when i use this structure:

```
 sign_in_data: [{date:"",time_in:"",time_out:""}]
```

my database looks like this:

```
sign_in_data[0][date]: "",
sign_in_data[0][time_in]: "",
sign_in_data[0][time_out]: ""
```

but it should look like this:

```
sign_in_data: [
{
   date: "2015-06-08",
   time_in: "17:35",
   time_out: "17:35"
},
]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read ``mongodb`` docs.. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html implement something like this within an express route callback.

Comment: Or is the problem getting data from the ajax submission?

Comment: i think the problem is just how to structure the assignment of my user variable to send it over to the route, so when i insert it it will maintain my mongo db structure

Comment: Could you show me a sample using the aggregate for my schema @PatrickRoberts, i think this is what i should be using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment when you are configuring express, review if you are using this line of code:

In case you are using Express 4.x version

**Note**: you need to have [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#express-route-specific) installed.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

---

In case you are using Express 3.x version

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

---

I did a test example where the property cars is an an array of objects send from the html file, and it is saving as you want in the database.

So this is my express server file:

```
// ..

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
  var user = {
    username: req.body.username,
    age: req.body.age,
    cars: req.body.cars
  };

  db
    .collection('user')
    .insert(user, function (err, result) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

      res.send(result);
    });
});

// ..
```

database data inserted:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5578b48f1e8cdf0520bdf76f"),
    "username" : "wilsonbalderrama",
    "age" : "29",
    "cars" : [
        {
            "name" : "Ferrari",
            "color" : "Red"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Mustang",
            "color" : "Gray"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my html file where I am sending the data, you can review it in this gist file:
https://gist.github.com/wilsonbalderrama/62f76a348c0aa217cdd9

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this seems like it might work but im having a problem...i sent two objects similarly to what you did through my ajax request but now in my route my request body looks like this:                                                          'user[created_at]': '2015-06-10 18:08',
  'user[updated_at]': '2015-06-10 18:08',
  'sign_in_data[date]': '',
  'sign_in_data[time_in]': '' and i cant seem to access the individual elements to recreate my whole object @Wilson Balderrama

Comment: thanks for your help and inspiration, what i ended up doing was sending over one object, and creating an array of objects in my route and merging them to form my one complete object and then inserting that in the database